# Convert date to floating number since epoch

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have a date as 02-12-2012 (dd-mm--yyyy) and wish to convert it into a float since the epoch. How would I do it using time.mktime() to convert this. If need be I'm happy to include the time as 00:00.

When I try to do it I get:

```
TypeError: argument must be 9-item sequence, not str
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`time.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) to create the [`struct_time`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time) that `time.mktime` expects:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.mktime(time.strptime('02-12-2012', '%d-%m-%Y'))
1354424400.0
```

Comment: Thanks, and that will then be the time as 02-12-2012 00:00. Ok I'll use the time.strptime method to convert it first.

Comment: When I did it I get the time as: 1354406400.0
I did: import time

a= '02-12-2012'
b = time.strptime(a, '%d-%m-%Y')


c= time.mktime(b)

print c

Comment: @user94628: `time.mktime` returns the time in local time, not UTC.  We get different results, because we are in different time zones.

Comment: Ok understand now. Can it be returned in UTC time though?

Comment: Skimming through the docs, I did not see a function for UTC.  However, you may want to rad them more thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) to do the conversion.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> epoch = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)
>>> my_date = datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 2)
>>> print (my_date - epoch).days * 3600 * 24
1354406400
```